# Singular perturbation methods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

Use singular perturbation methods to obtain a uniform approximate solution to the following problems. In each case assume $0 < \epsilon \ll 1$ and $0<x<1$.
$$ \epsilon y''-(2-x^2)y=-1.$$
with $y'(0)=0$ and $y(1)=1$.

I find a problem in the Book of Applied Mathematics of J. David Logan in the page 121, exercise 1.h. I solved with finite differences in order to understand how it looks the real the solution but my method of perturbations says that the solution is so different. I solved it like this

There are two layers near $x = −1$ and $x = 1$. The outer solution, which is valid in the interval (−1, 1), away from the layers is
$$y_0=\frac{1}{2-x^2}$$
In the layer near $x=1$ set $\tau=(1−x)/\delta(\epsilon)$. We find $\delta= \sqrt{\epsilon}$ with inner equation, $Y_i''-Y_i=1$ to leading order,
$$Y_i(\tau)=1+ae^{\tau}-(1+a)e^{\tau}$$
In the layer near $x=−1$ set  $\tau=(1−x)/\delta(\epsilon)$ .We find $\delta= \sqrt{\epsilon}$
with inner equation, to leading order, $(Y_i^*)'' − Y_{i}^* = −1$. The inner solution is
$$Y_i(\tau)=1+be^{\tau}-(1+b)e^{\tau}$$
Matching gives $a = b = 1$ and the uniform approximation is
$$y(t)=\frac{1}{2-x^2}-e^{(x-1)/\sqrt{\epsilon}}-e^{(x+1)/\sqrt{\epsilon}}$$
This solution is so different from the one I found with the numerical method.

Comment: Check if your solution satisfies the boundary condition. Decide for one of $x$ or $t$.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced this equation has a boundary layer structure.  The leading order solution ($\epsilon \to 0$) satisfies both given conditions.

Comment: Its correct look at the page of the book https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLp2k.png o.o

Comment: Yes I know (I went to check my copy earlier), but I'm still a bit suspicious that it might be a typo, and that it should maybe be $Y'$ instead of $Y$.  I've tried a few times to make a boundary layer at $x = 1$ work out, and so far the matching doesn't seem to work.  Can you add a bit more detail on how you got the inner solutions?

Comment: @DMcMor I also think that its a typo error. Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 2):

Since the DE involves only $y'$ and $y''$, not $y$, it's just a first-order equation in $v = y'$: $\epsilon v' - (2-x^2) v = -1$, with initial condition $v(0)=0$.  That has
the solution $v(x) = - \epsilon^{-1} e^{-x(x^2-6)/(3\epsilon)} F(x)$ where
$$ F(x) = \int_0^x e^{z(z^2-6)/(3\epsilon)}\; dz $$
Now I think you can use steepest descent to approximate the integral.

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti the original question had $y'$ rather than $y$, see the edit history.